# How to get FormatProvider from Autodesk.AutoCAD.Geometry.Point3d

Tags: c#, .net, autocad, autocad-plugin

I have some Point3d stored as text in the `DataGridView` cell.

```
Autodesk.AutoCAD.Geometry.Point3d px = new Point3d ( 100.0 , 123.0 , 0.0); // for example
row.Cells["IDS_ReferenePoint"].Value = px.ToString();
```

so I have the value: `"(100.0,123.0,0.0)"`

Now I need to reverse that operation - read that point from `DataGridView` cell and convert to `Point3d` object. So I may do it by remove `(`, `)` split text by separating columns sign `,` and each coordinate parse to double.

But I'm afraid that on other PC with different language settings `,` will be decimal places separator, and for example `[SPACE]` would be a coordinate separator.

Is there an easy way to get `FormatProvider` default used in `Point3d.ToString()` ? depended on user PC configuration?

Comment: Why don’t you simplify the issue? Override ToString and create your own formatted text with a distinct separator? Maybe the ~ character? This way you only need to split the array using the delimiter as there are no parentheses. Finally, you don’t have to override ToString, the main thing it you just construct the formatted text yourself. Keep it simple and prevent the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the `Point3d` format is not related to the Windows decimal separator. I used to use French versions of AutoCAD and the decimal separator for AutoCAD is the dot whatever the Windows settings (comma is the default windows decimal separator for French versions). And the comma is the coordinate separator for AutoCAD points, vector, matrices.

So, I think you do not have to care to `Point3d.ToString()` format which is always the same whatever the culture version.